# How to determine whether the passed array is 1-D, 2-D, OR N-D array

Tags: c++, c, multidimensional-array

I want to write a function which will accept an array as a input argument.
and the function should print all the elements of the array.

> ```
> print_array(arr)
> {
>   //print all the elemnts of arr.
> }
> ```

I don't know how to do that.

I think first we need to findout whether the passed array is 1-D or 2-D or 3-D and so on...array

Because, to print the elemnts of:

> ```
>                             1-D array, you need only 1 for loop.
>                             2-D array, you need only 2 for loop.
>                             3-D array, you need only 3 for loop.
> ```

But, I dont know how you'll indetify whether its 1-D, 2-D or N-D array.
Please Help.

Comment: How about modifying the function signature as follows: `print_array(type *array, int n_dimensions, int *dimensions)`?

Comment: I cant paas the dimention as a argument in the function. The Function will only accept the array's base address as its input. And its upto the function's developer to identify whether its 1-D or 2-D or 3-D array...and based on this, he has to print all its element.

Comment: @VikasChhipa: Once the array has been converted to a pointer, it's impossible to recover that information. The only options are to pass the dimensions to the function, or pass a reference to the array without converting to a pointer, as in eq-'s answer.

Comment: gslices are the standard way to represent multidimensional arrays with C++.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/valarray/gslice/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can actually find out the exact number of dimensions pretty easily, with a single overload using C++11's [`std::rank`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/rank) type trait:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<class T, unsigned N>
void print_dimensions(T (&)[N]){
  static unsigned const dims = std::rank<T>::value + 1;
  std::cout << "It's a " << dims << "-D array, you need "
            << dims << " for-loops\n";
}
```

---

However, you don't actually need `std::rank` at all to print all the elements; this can easily be solved with a simple overload:

```
namespace print_array_detail{
template<class T>
void print(T const& v){ std::cout << v << " "; }
template<class T, unsigned N>
void print(T (&arr)[N]){
  for(unsigned i=0; i < N; ++i)
    print(arr[i]);
  std::cout << "\n";
}
}

template<class T, unsigned N>
void print_array(T (&arr)[N]){ print_array_detail::print(arr); }
```

[Live example.](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f4622fabef36947fcf7fcdad6de1be58)

Comment: In C++03, use [`boost::rank`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/rank.html), from Boost.TypeTraits.

Comment: @ecatmur: Or just write it yourself, there's even an example implementation on cppreference. :)

Comment: so the function print_array itself will have to be templated as well?

Comment: @Gir: Yes, otherwise you couldn't accept different types of arrays.

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks man...its working. Since, i am weak in templates...i didn't understand the meaning of print_array(T (&arr)[N]) ...but i'll try to understand it by my own :-)

Comment: @VikasChhipa: It's a reference to an array. The type of the array elements (`T`), aswell as the size of the array (`N`), are deduced by the compiler from the passed argument.

Comment: @Xeo: Hey, I was wondering why we need to take care of (N) in function " print_array(T (&arr)[N]){} " ??  Bcoz...inside this function, you're just calling "print_array_detail::print(arr);" that means you are not making use of (N)...then why we need to take N ???

Comment: @VikasChhipa: Because it's needed to make the function match only a real array.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve something to this end through templates and overloading in C++. Consider

```
template<size_t X, size_t Y>
int sum_array_dimensions(int (&arr)[X][Y])
{
  // it's 2d
  return X + Y;
}

template<size_t X, size_t Y, size_t Z>
int sum_array_dimensions(int (&arr)[X][Y][Z])
{
  // it's 3d
  return X + Y + Z;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you could encode in a parameter the number of dimensions, and pass a unidimensional array

```
#define N1 10
#define N2 100
void function(unsigned dimensions, int* array)
{ switch(dimension):
  { case 1:
      for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
      { ... array[i] ...
      }
      break;
    case 2:
      for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
      { for (int j=0;j<N;j++)
        { ... array[i*N+j] ...
        }
      }
      break;
    case 3:
      for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
      { for (int j=0;j<N;j++)
        { for (int k=0;k<N;k++)
          { ... array[i*N2+j*N+k] ...
          }
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

if N is a power of 2 you can optimize the multiplication with `<<` left shift (`x*2^n == x<<n`)
**edit** extended solution

```
// the array is 0-indexed
void function(unsigned* dimensions, int* array)
{ //dimensions[0] = number of dimensions
  //dimensions[1 ... dimensions[0] ] the dimensions themselves
  for(int i=1,n=1;i<=dimensions[0];i++)
  { n*=dimensions[i]; }
  /* if the order in the array happens to be the wanted one */
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
  { print( array[i] );
  }
  /* otherwise the dimensions are specified in the dimension array */
  for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
  { int k=0;
    int temp=i;
    int base=1;       
    for(int j=1;j<=dimensions[0];j++)
    { k+=(temp%dimension[j])*base;
      base*=dimension[j];
      temp/=dimension[j];
    }
    print(array[k]);
  }   
  */
```

Comment: the nested loops are needed if the dimensions order is not the default one. In the edited example i replaced the nested loop with a for over the dimensions. (I initially didn't want to include the extended example, as the OP already found a satisfactory answer)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the size of array is lost when you pass it to a function (unless you pass by reference). So you can do something like this:

```
/* this function does the work */
template <typename T>
void bar(T* arr, size_t n_dims, size_t* sizes)
{
    std::cout << n_dims << " dimension(s)\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_dims; ++i)   // for each dimension
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizes[i]; ++j) ; // for each element
}

/* These are helper overloads to call bar with correct arguments. */
/* You'll need to provide one for each number of dimension you want to support */

template<typename T, size_t N>
void foo(T (&arr)[N])
{
    size_t sizes[] = {N};
    bar(arr, 1, sizes);
}

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
void foo(T (&arr)[N][M])
{
    size_t sizes[] = {N, M};
    bar(arr, 2, sizes);
}

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t M, size_t O>
void foo(T (&arr)[N][M][O])
{
    size_t sizes[] = {N, M, O};
    bar(arr, 3, sizes);
}

int main()
{
    int arr1[42];
    int arr2[2][2];
    int arr3[2][3][4];
    foo(arr1);
    foo(arr2);
    foo(arr3);
}
```

[Live example.](http://ideone.com/dEDIn)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it. But you can write 3 different functions with same name and different arguments (diff arrays types), then each function will treat it's own array.